# Binding different menu with different fragment with Navigation component

Tags: android, kotlin, android-toolbar, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I have an activity with BottomNavigationBar.

I show app logo in middle in toolbar by default.

Now I have to show SearchBar on entire toolbar when one of the bottomNavigation item is selected. Also, I want to revert to default toolbar view (one with logo in middle) on selecting any other bottomNavigation item.

How can i do this with Navigation component?

If I have to use ViewSwitcher or ActionMode, the whole idea of navigation component will have to be dropped as I can handle a few fragment transaction by myself.

Help me out here.

Comment: So you have a Toolbar in your Activity, but it is completely different if you're on one particular bottom navigation item?

Comment: Lets say i have 2 activity with different toolbars but i want to use single activity arch but toolbars should be changed as it was happening previously.

Comment: @ianhanniballake if this is supposed to handled by app devs or what i am asking is bad design, let me know and i will make changes accordingly. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's two approaches to do this:

**1) Have each Fragment implement its own Toolbar**

This approach gives you the ultimate flexibility in what each Fragment is responsible for, but is more suitable if you have many different types of Fragments or need scrolling behavior that is different for each Fragment.

**2) Use a OnNavigatedListener to change your Activity's Toolbar**

The `NavController` allows you to attach any number of [`OnNavigatedListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/navigation/NavController.OnNavigatedListener) instances, which give you a callback whenever the current destination / item changes.

This allows you to write code in your Activity such as:

```
navController.addOnNavigatedListener { navController, destination ->
  if (destination.id == R.id.search_destination) {
    // Update your Toolbar to be a SearchBar
  } else {
    // Reset it back to a standard Toolbar
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I applied the first approach. One of my fragments toolbar was CollapsingToolbar and it was causing 72px of paddingTop to ConstraintLayout when that fragment is displayed. Can you tell why this was happening? I handled it in onDestroyView() of that particular fragment by setting it to zero.

Comment: `<ConstraintLayout><FrameLayout><fragment-content including collapsingToolbar/></FrameLayout></ConstraintLayout>`. Here the FrameLayout has toptop constraint of parent but 72 px padding was seen in ConstraintLayout (density of phone was 428 dpi). Before adding fragment with CollapsingToolbar, it was zero. And it persisted even after the fragment was replaced.

Comment: If you're using `fitsSystemWindows` anywhere in your layouts, make sure you are calling `ViewCompat.requestApplyInsets` in each Fragment's `onViewCreated` to ensure they have the right insets